# use virtual mouse control to click on screen keyboard

Tags: c#

My project currently is using eye tracker to control the mouse cursor on the screen.
I need to use this virtual mouse cursor movement to type a letter.

I am able to move the cursor around and my left right click functioning well in all active windows. However, it is unable to select the keys on the on-screen keyboard.

Anybody know what is that problem?

Comment: What code are you currently using to click at the cursor position?...

Comment: I am using c# programming, using user32.dll for the cursor mouse event input.